# React Material UI Grid align items conditionally to either left or right of screen

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, material-ui

I am creating a chatbot and using React and Material UI. I am running into a problem with the Grid component. I am trying to align the bot messages to the left side of the screen and the user messages on the right side of the screen, however it is not working.

I have tried using alignItems prop on the Grid component, I have also tried using the CSS property `float='right'` and `float='left'`. But both do not seem to work.

I have a code sandbox link below showing a minimum reproducible example. Any help will be appreciated.

**https://codesandbox.io/s/react-chat-cuvfm?file=/src/App.js**

**Current Output:**
[image]

**Intended Output:**
All the blue bubbles should be at the right end of the screen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as i could see if the message has ID = 0 then it's user message. Then,
in your `ChatBubble`  component , in JSX add

**In ChatBubble styles.js**

```
  userChatBubbleOrientation: {
    justifyContent: "flex-end"
  },
  recipientChatBubbleOrientation: {
    justifyContent: "flex-start"
  }
```

**In ChatBubble Component**

```
  const chatBubbleOrientationStyles =
    props.message.id === 0
      ? {
          ...styles.userChatBubbleOrientation
        }
      : {
          ...styles.recipientChatBubbleOrientation
        };
```

```
<Grid
  container
  style={chatBubbleOrientationStyles}
>
```

Use [flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Flexbox) instead of float. Never use float for layout purposes. Also, Material UI uses flexbox so make use of that by adding  justifyContent:flex-end to your bot(user) messages to align them their content ( img + text ) to the right

Comment: Thanks it worked, I have updated the code sandbox link so it can help others.

Comment: I have also requested to edit your answer to fix variable naming inconsistencies as compared to the sandbox.

Comment: Can you explain why we should not use float?

Comment: @dracarys as stated here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/float The element is removed from the normal flow of the page, though still remaining a part of the flow . It was used a lot before flexbox and cssgrid came around because there was no other solution. But now it's used mostly when you want to wrap some text around an image ( like in the float: left; example in the mdn link i've shared ) . ALso, like i said in my answer, Material UI is based on flexbox layout. So why not use it then ?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the `float` property, you can just set `marginLeft: 'auto'` in ChatBubble/styles.js

This will set the left margin as max as possible for the user chat bubble also, adding `marginRight` to the recipient chat bubble is not necessary. So, you can avoid handling orientation for the recipient.

```
  userChatBubbleOrientation: {
    // float: "right",
    marginLeft:'auto'
  },
  recipientChatBubbleOrientation: {
    // float: "left"
    // marginRight:'auto'
  },
```